# Group by on List Items on millions

Tags: .net

Im writing Query to Azure Table Storage to pull data of about 40 millions record, I receive data @ Client end but when i convert to toList(), it throws Out of Memory exception.

Can any one tell me how to load 40 millions of data into memory, I have to store all 40 millions record and perform Group Operation on those 40 million records, Please suggest proper way to handle Out of memory exception .

Comment: Add more memory to the machine.

Comment: Perhaps store them in a DB first (without holding the complete list in memory) and than perform the grouping operations you need against the DB.

Comment: How many of the properties are you bringing back to store in memory? All fields that are available - or only what you need? In other words, what is the density of the records you are trying to group?

Comment: I using Azure table Storage. I cant use other datasources for storing records. Im bringing aroung 6-7 string type properties. I get count 49,00,000 ot 50,00,000 records. In future it may go up furthur. Once i perform group, count comes to 200 records.